# Having trouble implementing the begin() and next() functions for my Go linked list. First time using Go

Tags: go, linked-list, iterator

So I am trying to implement my own linked list in Go. I believe I have everything correct, but can't check because it's not complete yet. The structs and interfaces were given to me, so they HAVE to be correct. The functions are all my work. Any help regarding the Next and begin functions would be greatly appreciated. it appears I can't return the *it in the next function.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vector struct {
  num [] interface{} 
  size int
}

type VectorIterator struct {
  x Vector
  i int
}

type List struct {
  l *ListIterator
}

type ListIterator struct {
  num interface{}
  next *ListIterator
}

type Container interface {
  begin() Iterator
  append (v interface{})
}

type Iterator interface {
  next() Iterator
  isEnd() bool
  Deref () interface {}
}

func (it *ListIterator) isEnd() bool {
  if it.next == nil {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

func (it *VectorIterator) isEnd() bool {
if it.Next() == nil {
return true
} else {
return false
}
}

```
func (it *ListIterator) Deref() interface {} {
  return it.num
}

func (it *ListIterator) append(v interface{}) {
  for {
    it.Next()
    if it.isEnd() == true {
      break
    }
  }
  it.Next()
  it.num = v
}

func (it *ListIterator) begin() Iterator {

}

func (it *ListIterator) Next() Iterator {
  if it.isEnd() == false {
    it = it.next
  }
  return *it
  
}
```

Comment: Describe what you expect Next to do and return.   For example, is the purpose of the function advance to the next list item and return true if there is a next item?   Also, describe the purpose of begin.

Comment: " I believe I have everything correct, but can't check because it's not complete yet" you don't have to wait until it's complete to check your code.  You will never regret time spent adding tests to your code, and the best time to add them, is while you write the code, not after https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/add-a-test

Comment: Yes the purpose of the function is to advance to the next list item, and my professor was extremely vague on what begin does. They just said that we need to add a begin() Iterator to the container. That is literally it

Comment: `begin()` seems like it should return the start node of your linked list - a *ListIterator. Your Iterator interface definition also has a `next()` which you might want to change to `Next()`.